# Socket Communication Protocol/Standard

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I'm working on a project that involves several applications on several computers. The main application is a C++ socket server running on a CentOS server, and the client application is a Java program running on client PCs.

These will communicate back and forth using sockets. I have defined a set of commands and arguments that they will need to implement in order to support everything.

I've thought of several options, but I can't seem to find the perfect one..

- Should the C++ and Java program write their own classes/parsers for validate the messages?
- Should I create an XML file (served over HTTP) that defines all of the communication messages? (That the server/client would parse and create actions for)
- Or use some kind of third party library (Google Protocol Buffers?)

The point is that when the Socket server sends a message `X`, then the client must know what to do with it. Same applies the other direction.

What would be the best way to implement this? Having the XML file would be nice, as the client/server may parse it and create methods/actions based on the data. But a more clearer approach would be to create classes that would do the parsing.

Comment: Why XML and not JSON? Also, if you want to debug your protocol easily, it is better to use a text-based protocol; but that is your choice ultimately.

Comment: The messages are text based.

Comment: Yes, but I was talking about the protocol in general (what wraps the messages etc)

Comment: If you want to use xml, JAXB annotations will simplify the Java side(marshal/unmarshal) while tinyxml will get you quick performance on the C++ side.

Comment: Why are you using two languages?  Java and C++ can do either end just fine and you wouldn't have to generate a cross language protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I always do this the binary way. First you must decide what underlying transport protocol to use, it could be UDP, TCP, TCS, SSL. I would start with the TCP, since it's very stable and easy to use.

A simple way to handle packages is by in each package begin with a number that specifies which package this is. The based on this number you send the package to a corresponding class that handles the data. This can be done easily in both C++ and Java. I think it's easier in C++ since there you can base don't he first number read in a entire struct, but in Java you generally have to read it primitive by primitive.

Remember that the standard over the internet is to use big-endian values, but the normal on the most machines today (Intel, AMD, ARM...) uses little-endian values. So in C++ you will have to flip all primitives before sending them. And you have to flip the received values as well. I don't know if Java does this for you...

Comment: You don't have to use big endian over TCP, you can just as easily  use little endian.

Answer (score 0):

[ICE by ZeroC](http://www.zeroc.com/index.html) is a cross platform and cross language library for TCP/IP communication between C++ and Java. I've used ICE to communicate between Linux/AIX/Solaris for C++/Java programs without problems. ICE uses a binary transfer protocol that does the big-endian/little-endian conversion for you. The downside of ICE is that you need to define the messages and calls using its custom language.